# PySpark Juypter Notebook Displays

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

I am quite new to jupyter notebook, and I am struggling to reveal my spark table (image 1) in a neater way similar to a normal panda dataframe (image 2). I am trying not to use pandas.

The display function doesnt work on spark dataframe :( Can someone help me? It will make it easier for me to analysis the spark table.
[image: :]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your spark session, add the config.

```
.config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True)
```

For example,

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
          .master("local") \
          .config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True) \
          .getOrCreate()
```

and just call the dataframe without `.show` as follows

```
df
```

that will print the result in this way.

[image]